# Apply command between different directory names

Tags: bash

I have directories A, B, C saved in path1
and directories A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3 are saved in path2

I have the same copy of "file.txt" saved in directories A, B, C in path1

I want to make a copy of "file.txt" in every directory in path2. I tried for loop as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
path1=path to directories A, B, C
path2=path to directories A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3
for i in $(cat dirname.txt); do #dirname.txt is a file located in path1 contain the directories names in path1 (i.e A, B, C)
cp $path1/${i}/file.txt $path2/${i}_*/
done
```

The previous code was unable to read the directories in the path2.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) can take multiple sources, but not multiple destinations. If you want to get the destination directories by expanding 
`"path2/${i}_"*/`, then you need a second `for` loop:

```
for i in A B C; do
   for j in "path2/${i}_"*/; do
      cp "$path1/$i/file.txt" "$j"
   done 
done
```

Alternatively, you could generate the target directory names yourself:

```
for i in A B C; do
   for j in "path2/${i}_"{1..3}/; do
      cp "$path1/$i/file.txt" "$j"
   done 
done
```

Don't forget that you should double-quote shell variable expansions by default, unless you have a specific reason not to quote.